# <div> Elements used for background?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Alright, so [I found this nice codepen](http://codepen.io/davidkpiano/pen/VmMWZW?css-preprocessor=stylus) that I'd like to use as a background to a specific section of my website.

However, each element is rendered by inserting a **div** element.

Anyway I can do something like,

```
<!-- everything down below is a background -->
<div class="bg">
</div>
<!-- Down below we have the real content being show -->
<div class="content">
<p>Content</p>
</div>
```

**What I tried**:

Wrote a new css element:

```
.background { z-index: -100; }
```

Catastrophic results:

[image]

**My question**:

As soon as I wrap the whole thing around a new div everything messes up like you see above. How can I have it as a background without killing the design?

Comment: look into css position and (possibly) z-index

Comment: @AndrewLi Please remove the hold if it's ok now.

Comment: I can't just remove the on hold status. 5 other user of >3000 reputation must [vote to reopen](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36415/how-do-you-reopen-a-closed-question).